# styles are not being added to a table

Tags: javascript, html, css, csv

I am trying to build an electron app that fetches a csv table and displays it as a csv formatted html table

I tried using the code below but the styles are not being applied to the table in the electron window

It is not throwing any error just displaying the table without styles

```js
const csv = `id,species,name
0,Panthera leo,Lion
1,Canis Lupus,Wolf
2,Capra hircus,Goat
3,Panthera pardus,Leopard
4,Equus zebra,Zebra`;

function fetchData() {
  return new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => res(csv), 1000));
}

getData();
async function getData() {
  //const response = await fetch('new.csv');
  //const data = await response.text();
  const data = await fetchData();
  let a;
  a = data.slice(15);
  a = a.replaceAll(',', '</td><td>');
  a = a.replaceAll('\n', '</tr><tr><td>');
  let start = "<table><tr><th>id</th><th>species</th><th>name</th><tr><td></tr>";
  let end = "</td></tr></table>";
  let semi = start.concat('', a);
  a = semi.concat('', end);
  a = a.replaceAll('<tr><td></tr></tr>', '');
  a = a.replaceAll('</tr>', '</td></tr>');
  a = a.replaceAll('</th></td></tr>', '</th></tr>');
  a = a.replaceAll('</td></td>', '</td>');
  document.write(a);
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  `enter code here` border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: `document.write` is deleting your existing HTML, including the CSS.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

1. Add a div to the body, with a class of *test*

```
<div class="test"></div>
```

2. Update the `document.write` to be `document.appendChild` like this:

```
document.querySelector('.test').appendChild(table);
```

**table** has to be a DOM element, so create it with `let table = document.createElement('table');` and then replace **a** with **tableContent**, like this:

```
const csv = `id,species,name
0,Panthera leo,Lion
1,Canis Lupus,Wolf
2,Capra hircus,Goat
3,Panthera pardus,Leopard
4,Equus zebra,Zebra`;

getData();
function getData() {
  //const response = await fetch('new.csv');
  //const data = await response.text();
  const data = csv;
  let tableContent;
  tableContent = data.slice(15);
  tableContent = tableContent.replace(/,/g, '</td><td>');
  tableContent = tableContent.replace(/\n/g, '</tr><tr><td>');
  let start = "<tr><th>id</th><th>species</th><th>name</th><tr><td></tr>";
  let end = "</td></tr>";
  let semi = start.concat('', tableContent);
  tableContent = semi.concat('', end);
  tableContent = tableContent.replace(/<tr><td><\/tr><\/tr>/g, '');
  tableContent = tableContent.replace(/<\/tr>/g, '</td></tr>');
  tableContent = tableContent.replace(/<\/th><\/td><\/tr>'/g, '</th></tr>');
  tableContent = tableContent.replace(/<\/td><\/td>/g, '</td>');
  let table = document.createElement('table');
  table.innerHTML = tableContent;
  document.querySelector('.test').appendChild(table);
}
```

Comment: "I don't think there is a problem with your styles" — You're right, the problem is with the JavaScript, but this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Quentin Can you please explain what I am doing wrong here ? Can I do the same thing without the DW ?